# Jenkins: Restricting test jobs to run on same slave as the job its testing

Tags: testing, configuration, jenkins, label

I've recently started to change my Jenkins jobs from being restricted to a certain slave to being restricted to a slave group identified by a label. However I have test jobs that I need to run on the same slave as the job that they're testing.

I need a way to tie two jobs together such that they can only be run on the same slave, but the slave is still chosen by Jenkins based on availability, etc.

Anyone know how to do this, or even if it's possible? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't you use
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin
and to pass the node name ${NODE_NAME} (see https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-JenkinsSetEnvironmentVariables) to the next build, that should be parametrized on the node label (that can be node name) using
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/NodeLabel+Parameter+Plugin

Comment: I ended up only needing to use Parameterized Trigger Plugin. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

> I need a way to tie two jobs together such that they can only be run on the same slave, but the slave is still chosen by Jenkins based on availability, etc.

I have the same problem, and I found Node Stalker Plugin
Right now the plugin can be found on the following url:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Node+Stalker+Plugin

Jenkins calls this plugin as

Job Node Stalker

on plugin management page. It will be part of Jenkins.